# Style not sticking in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, styles

I'm using Writer to modify a `.docx` file. The file was originally a "template" made by my professor with pre-configured styles for different parts of the document (spacing and indentations, etc.). However, I can't seem to get my changes to stick. Some paragraphs keep their style, but it seems like the last in a set of paragraphs with the same style go back to the "Header" style after I save, close, and reopen the document.

What could be causing the style to not stick? I can reopen the document, place my cursor in the paragraph, and select the style, and it changes to the way I want, but if I save and close, the change is forgotten.

Comment: Not that familiar with LO but certainly Word uses the paragraph mark AFTER the last character to store the definition of the preceding paragraph. I wonder if LOW is trimming too aggressively and losing the trailing para mark. Try adding a blank para after the end of your troublesome one and see if that is a work around. If so, it is probably a bug that needs reporting.

Comment: That workaround absolutely does work. I'll report it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Not that familiar with LO but certainly Word uses the paragraph mark AFTER the last character to store the definition of the preceding paragraph.

I wonder if LOW is trimming too aggressively and losing the trailing para mark.

Try adding a blank paragraph after the end of your troublesome one and see if that is a work around.

If so, it is probably a bug that needs reporting.